# Hamburger menu drop down onto a new line on xs resize

Tags: reactjs, navbar, react-bootstrap

When resizing using react-bootstraps navbar collapseOnSelect the hamburger menu works properly but at xs or below xs rather the hamburger menu is dropping down onto a new line below the logo creating a larger block than I would like the navbar to be on phone displays I'd like for it to stay on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand that right, the problem that you are facing is when the hamburger change it’s behavior for the smaller devices you would like it to stay dripping down directly below it and not taking the whole screen, right?

If I’m right, that’s the usual behavior for bootstrap hamburger. I would say that it will be better to follow this UX due to smaller devices having very different sizes of screens. But if you would like to change it’s normal behavior you could remove the following css class from your navbar

```
.collapse.navbar-collapse
```